# How can I convert a string to a file handle in perl?

Tags: string, perl, filehandle

I have a very big-size string `$s="dfasdfasdfafd...."`, of nearly 1,000,000 characters. I want to convert it to a file handle, making it look like this string is read from a file. But I don't want to store it to a temp file and read it.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: split the single str to array.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open a reference to a string:

```
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;

my $foo = "abc\ndef\n";
open my $fh, "<", \$foo;

while (<$fh>) {
  print "line $.: $_";
}
```

Output:

```
line 1: abc
line 2: def
```

Comment: It's no problem to write a string in the same manner. Can be useful with formats!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use OO-style then use [IO::String](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3A%3AString) package.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::String;

my $s="dfasdfasdfafd....\nabc";
my $io = IO::String->new($s);

while (my $line = $io->getline()) {
   print $line;
}

print "\nTHE END\n";

# write new line
$io->print("\nappend new line");

# back to the start
$io->seek(0, 0);

while ($io->sysread(my $line, 512)) {
   print $line;
}
```

Also you may use almost all methods described in [IO::Handle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3A%3AHandle) package.

This solution is useful when some of another package accepts only IO::Handle (IO::File) object to manipulate data.